# Is it possible to override drawRect on a class without inheritance?

Tags: ios, overriding, drawrect

I need to know if it is possible to override drawRect for a UI class globally. Something along the lines of the "appearance" class property. Essentially I need to use my own drawing routine for all buttons in the app. Preferably I don't want to inherit and have to set the class type on each button in the storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Class Category

```
@interface UIView (UIViewDR)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect;
@end


@implementation UIView (UIViewDR)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect { /* your implementation */ return; }
@end
```

You'll likely use a class other then UIView; like something that a button is built upon.

Comment: Out of interest does anyone know how this will react to inheritance. For instance if I implemented this for UI button, then I also wanted to say create a tab button that derives from UIButton, will my new TabButton's drawRect take precedence?

Comment: A method defined on a subclass always takes precedence.  If you want the parent method then you must call [super ...] explicitly (with the typical example being the init: methods).

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [UIAppearance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)?  I haven't looked into solving a problem like yours before, but I poked around a bit on google at it seems like UIAppearance might do the trick?

Comment: UIAppearance only lets you modify class level attributes. It does not as far as I can tell let you override or delegate methods sadly.